# Stringbuildier in loop, anything to do better?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

For each x Strings the output should be in quote and each String should be separated by a comma:

For example:

```
input: String String1 String2
output: "String","String1","String2"

input: String
output: "String"

TestBuildier testBuildier = new TestBuildier();
    testBuildier.concatString("Test","Test1","Test2");
}

public void concatString(String...value){
        StringBuilder newValue = new StringBuilder();
        for(String str: value){
            newValue.append("\"").append(str).append("\",");
        }
        newValue.deleteCharAt(newValue.length()-1);
        System.out.println(newValue);

    }
```

Output is `"String","String1","String2"` so it works. But I'm wondering maybe u guys would do here something different or this code looks ok?

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this with a Stream:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

String result = Arrays.stream(value)
                .map(s -> '"' + s + '"')
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: You can directly collect with out the intermadiate map step by using the 3args joining collector: `String newValue = Arrays.stream(value).collect(Collectors.joining("\",\"","\"", "\""));`

Answer (score 2):

Just use String.join:

```
System.out.println('"' + String.join("\",\"", values) + '"');
```